# Ping ECHO_REQUEST handling in linux

Tags: linux, unix, networking, ping, packet

What happens when a system receive a ping ECHO_REQUEST packet. And how the kernal handles it and send ECHO_REPLY to the sender of the 
packet. So, what is the program and port no. used to handle the ping echo request packet.

Comment: Network "pings" work different to the "normal" network requests you are probably used to. There is no port involved at all. A "ping" uses ICMP communication, not TCP or UDP. The concept of port numbers is only defined in those higher level protocols, not for ICMP packages. Also there is no "program" involved here, it is the network layer that acknowledges the in request itself. Do a bit research yourself, start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol

Comment: You can read this : http://superuser.com/questions/278498/how-does-ping-command-really-work

Comment: @arkascha Then what is the source of the ECHO_REPLY message ?

Comment: As said: it is generated directly in the network layer, just as TCP ACK packages for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)#Echo_reply